# Unable to execute/pass block of SQL code to Oracle through Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I am trying to pass block of SQL(Oracle) to fetch the results and store in excel using VBA. Connection established successfully and able to fetch results of a simple query. But while replacing the simple query with a block of SQL it returning an error.

**Note:** Because of limited access to DB, I am unable to create function. So trying to pass the same block of code in run time.

**Trying to achieve** - Fetching each table row count from DB and storing in excel by handling exception too

```vb
cnn_meta.Open (.....)
sqlQry = "DECLARE tmp_table VARCHAR2(125); table_does_not_exist EXCEPTION; PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -00942); row_cnt integer; " & vbCrLf & _
            "BEGIN FOR cntr IN (SELECT owner,table_name FROM all_tables where owner='APPQOSSYS')" & vbCrLf & _
            "  LOOP BEGIN tmp_table := cntr.owner || '.' || cntr.table_name; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(1) FROM ' || tmp_table ||' where rownum =1' into row_cnt; dbms_output.put_line(tmp_table || ' - ' || row_cnt); " & vbCrLf & _
            "        EXCEPTION WHEN table_does_not_exist THEN dbms_output.put_line('table dose not exists - ' || tmp_table); " & vbCrLf & _
            "            WHEN OTHERS THEN IF (SQLCODE = -942) THEN DBMS_Output.Put_Line('in exception'); ELSE DBMS_Output.Put_Line(tmp_table || ' - Dont have access\didnt exist'); END IF; " & vbCrLf & _
            "END; END LOOP; END;"
```

```vb
res_meta.Open sqlQry, cnn_meta, adOpenStatic
For iCols = 0 To res_meta.Fields.Count - 1
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = res_meta.Fields(iCols).Name
Next

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset res_meta
res_meta.Close
cnn_meta.Close
```

While I am executing the above code it returns below error

> Run-time error '3704':
>   Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

When I replaced the simple query to the above code it is working fine.

**Simple\Passed Query-**

```
sqlQry = "select owner,table_name, to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||owner ||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) Count " & _
    '         "from all_tables"
```

Comment: I think you can drop all instances of `vbCrLf` in the query

Comment: @Tim - Still getting the same error

Comment: Do you try to catch `dbms_output.put_line(tmp_table || ' - ' || row_cnt);`? You don't have access to dbms_output when you call Oracle via ADODB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is due to the `res_meta.Close` line

You can't close a recordset when no recordset was returned. Your `Select...` query *does* return a recordset, but from a quick glance it appears the other query makes a temp table and therefore does not return a recordset. Remove the line that is supposed to close the recordset, and the code should work.

The following method won't return anything if no recordset was returned.

```vb
res_meta.Open sqlQry, cnn_meta, adOpenStatic
On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print rs.EOF
On Error GoTo 0
If err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "No recordset was returned", vbCritical, "Error"
Else
    For iCols = 0 To res_meta.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = res_meta.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset res_meta
    res_meta.Close
End If
err.Clear
cnn_meta.Close
```

Comment: I have removed the res_meta.close, still same error

Comment: when I verified res_meta.status, it returns 0. So I think none is captured in recordset

Comment: I think you are still getting the error because you are trying to copy a non-existing recordset. I reckon no recordset exists hence the errors. On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: Yes exactly, *"I think you are still getting the error because you are trying to copy a non-existing recordset"*. There is no recordset, so you can't close it nor copy its values. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yup I understood the issue and thanks for your code to handle the situation, but in Oracle Developer I am able to fetch the results for the same code, then why it is not returning anything while invoking thru VBA code?

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle so unfortunately I cannot tell you